# Можно ли использовать Contact form 7 на wordpress на локальном сервере?

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-плагины, openserver

Если да, то можете пожалуйста объяснить, как этот плагин установить на openserver. У меня он выдает ошибку:  Использован некорректный синтаксис почтового адреса.

Answer (score 1):

> как этот плагин установить на openserver

1. Завести вебсервер на домене с нормальным синтаксисом (напр `wordpress.dev`)
2. Домен в обратном адресе CF7 должен совпадать с доменом "сайта" (напр `info@wordpress.dev`).

Но лучше делать сайт сразу на реальном хостинге. В крайнем случае в виртуалке с линуксом, но не а виндовых форках.